# Can I omit spec-required attributes and still use HTML validation in an Angular context?

Tags: html, angularjs, validation, src

How can I omit the `src` tag after `data-ng-src` tag and pass HTML validation (I use [html5-lint](https://github.com/mozilla/html5-lint))?

Currently, after

```
<img data-ng-src="{{ myImageSource }}" alt="my image description" />
```

I get:

> error: Element “img” is missing required attribute “src”

Comment: You're going to run into countless issues with linting Angular templates. Maybe try this instead? https://github.com/nikestep/grunt-html-angular-validate

Comment: Thanks, this is the best solution (I use gulp, so will use `https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-html-angular-validate`) ... If you want to post this as an answer...